# HAMA USB Hub Failing Under macOS Monterey & Apple Silicon M1

Tags: macos, usb, apple-silicon

**Edit:** macOS Monterey have issues with USB Hubs. You can watch topic from here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/683409

I’m using macOS Monterey 12.0.1 with Apple Silicon M1 iMac 24".

I bought Hama USB-C Hub, Multiport, 5 Ports, 2 x USB-A, USB-C, HDMI™, LAN/Ethernet (GTIN: 4047443436818) from Turkey at last month. As I read on both technical specifications and user manual, the USB-C port on device is bi- directional;  it both supports PD and data transfer.

[image]

I tested this functionality both Windows 10 & 11 and macOS with M1 (Apple Silicon) chip. On Windows , the port works bi-directional perfectly. However, Apple Silicon device not support data transfer from port, supports only power delivery. If I connect a USB-C device from mac port directly, it runs perfectly.

How can I tell if the fault is with my Apple silicon Mac or or caused a broken hub ?

Comment: Likely just the hub. Replace it and if it happens again use a different make/model of hub

Comment: I’ve gotten rid of your double negatives with an edit. The short answer is you need more details and triage and willl have to rely on vendor support a bit and llegwork to get a specific solve. The general answer is it should work

Comment: If you focus the second image B, I understand that data mode will only usable with mobile devices and laptops & desktops are supports power delivery & charge only. It is a little bit confusing. Or am I wrong?

Comment: This post is going to help so many people. Be sure you accept your answer. Feel free to copy any useful parts from my answer into yours. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized  that I attached the hub to USB & ThunderBolt 4 port. Due to my M1 iMac cannot charged with PD, USB controller closes this port I think. After connecting the hub to USB-C 3.2 port, USB-C port on the hub was started working. This is not an issue, it causes from misunderstanding how the iMac ports behave. **After few days, USB-C port on Hub disabled again. Changing the port of Hub a few days apart is the the only solution right now.**

Answer (score -1):

I use several USB-C and Thunderbolt 3 and Thunderbolt 4 hubs and they work for data transfer like you report with windows. The hubs work on macOS and windows and it doesn’t matter M1 or Intel cpu for our hubs. I don’t have a Hama to test, though.

I’m using Anker and CalDigit hubs mostly for work.

Not all USB cables and ports are certified, so I would start with trying a different hub or cable if you have them. If not, you will need some extra skills to read the system logs and/or reach out to vendor support.

- Apple will likely ask you to update your Apple software and check with the vendor.
- The vendor will likely ask you to check with Apple.

Keeping good notes on the OS version and open system profiler to get details on the USB device will help if you end up crowd sourcing if your specific vendor, device firmware work with specific macOS version.

Comment: Data transfer of usb-c port is running on iPadOS & M1 iPad Pro. So I think it is based on M1 Macs.

Comment: It could be that device isn’t seen as supported and gets disabled for some reason.  All my devices work with iPads older than M1 and with M1. Sorry yours isn’t working as expected @berkb

Comment: Boldly ignoring that hundreds of tech pages report about serious issues with Monterey and USB 3, as well as that the two threads about this topic in Apple's own user and development forums belongs to the longest threads in the history of these forums is either total ignorance or denial and both deserves a downvote. And this has nothing to do with hubs or cables, all of these devices work fine on Intel Macs running Big Sur and they all work fine on all Windows/Linux PCs in the field, so there is nothing wrong with the devices or the cables.